# musicbrainz unable to count artists by country

Tags: mysql, sql, musicbrainz

Hi i am using the musicbrainz database and i am having trouble counting all the Artists for each country, but no matter what country's i try i get the same error, even when i try using like. PLease can anyone show me what i have done wrong ?

> ERROR:  column "%u%" does not exist LINE 7: WHERE AREA.NAME LIKE "%u%"

```
SELECT COUNT(artist.name)
FROM artist
JOIN area ON artist.area = area.id 
JOIN label ON area.id = label.area
JOIN country_area ON area.id = country_area.area
JOIN release_country ON country_area.area = release_country.country
WHERE AREA.NAME LIKE "%dom"
GROUP BY release_country.country
limit 5;
```

UPDATE:

```
musicbrainz_db=> SELECT COUNT(artist.name)
musicbrainz_db-> FROM artist
musicbrainz_db-> JOIN area ON artist.area = area.id
musicbrainz_db-> JOIN label ON area.id = label.area
musicbrainz_db-> JOIN country_area ON area.id = country_area.area
musicbrainz_db-> JOIN release_country ON country_area.area = 
release_country.country
musicbrainz_db-> WHERE AREA.NAME LIKE '%dom'
musicbrainz_db-> GROUP BY release_country.country
musicbrainz_db-> limit 5;
```

> ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout

My teacher just came over and said it wont work with out a sub query ?

```
select area.name, label_count
from area
where label_count in 
(
    select area.name, count(label.id) as "label_count"
    from area
    JOIN label on area.id = label.area
    group by area.name
);
```

the sub query works fine but the main query fails ? any idea why.

Comment: show more code  .. plase  . show the code where you use this query

Comment: Try with single quotes instead of double. Also, you usually (almost always?) want to use a SELECT TOP with a LIMIT statement.

Comment: im running it in a terminal to a internal server, that is all the code.

Comment: your teacher is right. Your third join is not between area and another table so it will not be executed. You need a subquery for the third join and the primary query for the first two

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(artist.name)
FROM artist
JOIN area ON artist.area = area.id 
JOIN label ON area.id = label.area
JOIN country_area ON area.id = country_area.area
JOIN release_country ON country_area.area = release_country.country
WHERE AREA.NAME LIKE '%u%'
GROUP BY release_country.country
limit 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

See MySQL official documentation

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html

and try with single quote

```
SELECT COUNT(artist.name)
FROM artist
JOIN area ON artist.area = area.id 
JOIN label ON area.id = label.area
JOIN country_area ON area.id = country_area.area
JOIN release_country ON country_area.area = release_country.country
WHERE AREA.NAME LIKE '%dom'
GROUP BY release_country.country
limit 5;
```

double quotes are used for column name